# How to read an not in excel format or corrupted excel file using java

Tags: java, excel

I need to download some data in webpage in the form of excel file for that webpage contains excel image button. When i click the button an excel file downloads with containing some data which i need. But when i tried to open the downloaded file it showing an error "The file you are trying to open , File is in different format then specified by the file extension or corrupted data. Because of this error i am unable to read the data by using java.

Comment: use java apache poi framework to write pure excel with supported format

Comment: i have saved the downloaded file as somename.xls when i tried to read that file it showing the error i have used apache poi only

Comment: Google "extension hardening" - it's probable that the downloaded "Excel" file is really just HTML served with an Excel MIME type.

Comment: If i want get the downloaded file to original excel file then i need to open the sheet by manually and save as excel file type again then only i can read or write in that file.but i want to do all the work by program only how to solve this.

Comment: In order to really answer this question, people need to know what's in the file. Could you copy the first 100 bytes from an example file using a hex editor and paste them into a code block in your question?

Comment: If you Google as I suggested you will find how to disable Office extension hardening on your machine: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/948615.  But that will only affect opening the file in excel: if you are using some other tool which expects a "real" Excel file you will still have problems.

Answer (score 0):

try to save it as xlsx as there are two kind of work book provided by poi that is for xls and another is for xlsx.